# Wrapping $watch/$timeout in function breaks 2-way binding if bound resource is loaded async

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

TL;DR
[Check the example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ca8McLRXCZseQwDEKrZA)

I have a directive with an isolated scope where the scope looks like this: `{ obj: '=' }`. I then need to apply that value to a model property:

```
link (scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.model = {};
  scope.model.v = scope.obj.value;
}
```

Then I need to make sure that when `scope.model.value` changes the parent scope's property is updated as well. So I do something like this:

```
scope.$watch('obj.value', function (a,b) {
  if (!angular.equals(a, b)) {
    $timeout(function () {
      scope.model.v = a;
    });
});
```

And visa versa for binding in the other direction.

This works perfectly, but I wanted to put this in a reusable function so I'm not always repeating that chunk of code.

So I came up with this:

```
/**
 * scope: the scope being altered
 * a:     string representing the first property being bound
 * b:     string representing the second property being bound
 * objEq: boolean to be passed to the scope.$watch object equality argument
 */
var bind = function (scope, a, b, objEq) {
    objEq = typeof objEq === 'undefined' ? false : objEq;

    var getPointer = function (s) {

      var parts = s.split('.');
      var pointer = scope;
      var key = parts.slice(-1);

      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length-1; i++) {
        var part = parts[i];
        pointer = pointer[part];
      }

      return {pointer: pointer, key: key};
    };

    var aObj = getPointer(a);
    var bObj = getPointer(b);

    scope.$watch(a, function (n, o) {
        if (!angular.equals(n, o)) {
            $timeout(function () {
                bObj.pointer[bObj.key] = n;
            });
        }
    }, objEq);

    scope.$watch(b, function (n, o) {
        if (!angular.equals(n, o)) {
            $timeout(function () {
                aObj.pointer[aObj.key] = n;
            });
        }
    }, objEq);
};
```

This works great if the parent scope's property is hard coded into the controller, but breaks if the property is the result of an http request. I can't figure out what is going on here. Could someone explain this?

[Here is an example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ca8McLRXCZseQwDEKrZA)

---

Also, just wrapping the `scope.$watch` in a function doesn't break it.

This works:

```
function (scope, a) {
  scope.$watch(a, function (n, o) {
    if (!angular.equals(n, o)) {
      $timeout(function () {
        scope.otherProperty = n;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `scope.$apply();` inside the watch and timer. remove it, it is not needed, it will only show digest error. `$timeout` will trigger a digest.

Comment: Thanks, removed it. wasn't giving me any errors but yeah, it's not needed.

Comment: Ok. I cannot really access fiddle, plunker i can.. :(

Comment: Created plunk, changed the example link

Comment: I see it does not work with bind function is because it is copying the  primitive not the object reference. http://plnkr.co/edit/jCaxQH?p=preview

Comment: hmmm, so there is no way to bind a specific primitive value rather than the entire object? Also, if this is the case, why does it work when it's not wrapped in a function?

Comment: It does with watch is because you are updating the value manually when the other one is updated. But if copy primitive to primitive it wont really update each other once other one has been updated, because both objects point to different heap memory location. When you copy one object to another variable, both of them will be pointing to same memory location so adding a property or updating a property on one will reflect on botht he variables.

Comment: Unlike other languages js does not have "copy by reference" everything is "by value" and when we copy one object to another we are actually copying the reference value of one to another

Comment: So, if I wanted to bind `scope.obj.value` with `scope.model.v` is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a solution thanks to @PSL's explanation of what was going wrong.

I just needed to call the `getPointer` function within `scope.$watch`.

```
scope.$watch(a, function (n, o) {
  if (!angular.equals(n, o)) {
    var bObj = getPointer(b);
    $timeout(function () {
      bObj.pointer[bObj.key] = n;
    });
  }
}, objEq);
```

examples:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcarleton/u9498fLh/4/)
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ca8McLRXCZseQwDEKrZA?p=preview)